# How to capture event when user has entered a new character in a EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I Have a EditText restricted to numeric characters, and i need to perform special actions when user enters numbers and when user press "." character on virtual keyboard.

```
numberEditText = new EditText(this);
numberEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

I know that exists this listener:

```
numberEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {         
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {               
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But i don't know how to use it to achieve my needs.

Any help will be grated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try textChagedListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how -

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

       @Override    
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
       }

       @Override    
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int before, int count) {
          if(s.equals("."))
            editText.setText("");
       }
      });
```

Comment: Hi, how to know last entered character?

Comment: it does not work... if i press "." the listener is not being called because android keyboard does not accept points as first characters of a edittext..

Comment: ok finally i achieved it using this answer combined with this line of code: numberEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL );

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Apparently it does not work for OP.

```
if(event.getKeyCode() == KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT) { ... }
```

could work. Maybe you have to add something in front of the "KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT"

All Keycodes are available here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_DOT) is not working because onEditorActionListener is not being called when i press "."

Answer (score 1):

Add a text changed listener.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

     //Do your stuff here

   }
  });
```

Comment: hi, how to know last entered character? it is possible to reset edit text content inside one of these methods to emtpy string?

Comment: it does not work... if i press "." the listener is not being called because android keyboard does not accept points as first characters of a edittext..

Comment: Is it? let me give it a try tomorrow then, apologies for not trying it with "." ; will try and update you.

Comment: You have your EditText input restricted by numbers right? Maybe change to normal settings and then catch the non digets on text change. Don't know if it works but you can give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You can use text watcher with your edittext like this

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

     //Do your stuff here

   }
  });
```

Comment: it does not work... if i press "." the listener is not being called because android keyboard does not accept points as first characters of a edittext..

Answer (score 1):

You can get last inout character with above code block.

getSelectionStart() gets cursor position. After enter a character cursor goes to right of this character. So you can get last entered character by (cursor position -1)

edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

```
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            String text = charSequence.toString();

            if (text.equals("")) return;

            int index = edt.getSelectionStart() - 1;

            Character lastCharacter = text.charAt(index);

            Log.v("LAST_CHARACTER", "Index: " + index + " --> " + lastCharacter.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
```